# extraction number from end of line in regex

Tags: regex

With a list like :

```
DEFE0000458
sdqsd000254
qdqsdq012525
qsdqs000125
012254104564
00012540001
00026a000a0
```

I try a regex to extract number in the end of line after the last 0
with the list, results are

```
458
254
12525
125
4564
1
no match
```

My regex:

```
(\d+[^0])$
```

seem to be a debut for me.

Comment: Maybe you want `.*0(\d+)$`? Or `[1-9][0-9]*$`

Comment: You may try: `[1-9]+$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression `[1-9]+$` should be sufficient.

```
$ cat input.txt 
DEFE0000458
sdqsd000254
qdqsdq012525
qsdqs000125
012254104564
00012540001
00026a000a0

$ grep -o '[1-9]\+$' input.txt 
458
254
12525
125
4564
1
```

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers can still contain zeros, you can use

```
.*0([1-9]\d*)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j9z6eP/3).

*Details*

- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `0` - a zero digit
- `([1-9]\d*)` - Group 1: a non-zero digit and then any zero or more digit chars
- `$` - end of a string/line.

So, Group 1 will hold the results you need. **Note** this regex requires the `0` to actually be there in the string/line before other digits.